# Interrupt systemd mount unit during boot

Tags: mount, boot, systemd

I've Btrfs RAID1 mounted during boot with this line in fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/storage /mnt/storage btrfs noatime 0 0
```

Few days ago I was checking data on some old disks, and to connect them  I had to disconnect one disk from the RAID first, because I don't have any free SATA ports left. Unfortunately the `/dev/disk/by-label/storage` points to the disk on SATA port I swapped.

Then, during boot, systemd waited 1 minute and 30 seconds apparently for the Btrfs filesystem to appear on a disk with completely different layout. After that I finally got root shell.

Is there any way to interrupt the systemd unit during boot? `^C` didn't work.

Note that whether the case I mentioned is a systemd bug (it is, isn't it?) is only secondary concern to me. Since I expect similar boot delays for *not gonna happen* events in future, I'd really like a way to interrupt those jobs, even if it means shooting myself in the foot.

You may suggest that I should append `x-systemd.device-timeout=0` to mount options, but that may not be desired and that's not what I'm asking for.

```
$ rpm -qi systemd
Name        : systemd
Version     : 216
Release     : 25.fc21
```

EDIT:

Apparently `/usr/lib/systemd/system/debug-shell.service` could probably be used. I have to try it.

EDIT2:

So the debug shell doesn't require any password. That's not what I want.